# How do I list all the questions I've *answered* under a specific tag?

Tags: support, tags

How do I list all the questions I've *answered* under a specific tag?

Comment: you should start by clicking a tag under the "Tags" header in your user page and see what happens

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
user:me [tag]
```

...will give you all your *posts* under the `tag` tag, whether they are answers or questions.

```
user:me [tag] isaccepted:1
```

...will give you all your *accepted* answers under the `tag` tag.

If you want *all* answers (and answers *only*), I'm afraid you must resort to calling [the API](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/help/), like this:

```
http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/users/50394/answers?page=1
```

Comment: It works without "isaccepted" too

Comment: @Motti but then you'll also find questions.

Comment: true, I haven't thought of that...

Comment: neat answer. makes me want favorites for answers

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Jeff I was able to figure it out. Here's the search syntax you can use:

```
user:50394 [json]
```

Replace the number part with your actual user id. This will also return questions you *asked* and not only questions you've *answered*.

Comment: or you can use user:me